# How to generate schema for yaml that supports anchors and aliases?

Tags: python, typescript, go, rust, yaml

I need to define the schema of a YAML configuration file. The model should support [yaml aliases and anchors](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/yaml-anchors-aliases-overrides-extensions/) so that a global configuration value could be overridden more specifically.

For example, maybe there’s a list of items which should take a object value which by default is defined at the top level and maybe you want to override for some objects by doing something like this:

```
globals:
  foo: &default_foo
    val: bar

my_config:
   items:
     - name: item1
       config: *default_foo
     - name: item2
       config:
         <<: *default_foo
         val: override_bar
```

I want to be able to describe this schema to users (and obviously to check validity programmatically). I’d like to make it clear to users via aliases that they can override values without having to manually write this in an example file.

Is there a way to do this schema generation in any commonly used high level language (primarily interested in Python & Typescript but happy to consider Rust or GoLang).

I specifically want to be able to easily make it known to users that they can override values using aliases. The file model is sufficiently complex that I really don’t want to have to manually provide an example file with handwritten documentation notes if at all possible.

For Python, for instance, I could use Pydantic & pydantic-yaml to define a model programatically but whilst aliases are parsed correctly (serialize yaml to model) it doesn’t appear that there’s a way to cleanly document the schema like this.

Comment: Are anchors and aliases really needed? They are a nice way to avoid repetitions, but they are an advanced and *optional* language feature (not all users will be familiar with them). Default values should be set as default values in the config implementation (e.g., pydantic) and the user can decide whether they want to use anchors.

Comment: @Plagon Anchors are optional features of a node, that doesn't make them (or aliases) optional language features, as you incorrectly state (see the  [YAML specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/)). Anchors and aliases are necessary to represent all but the most trivial data structures. Maybe you are confusing this with support for the merge key (`<<`), which is not mandatory. But as all language independent YAML tags in the domain `yaml.org` support is [strongly recommended](https://yaml.org/type/)

Comment: Yes, @Plagon, I’d like to be able to explicitly draw the user’s attention to the existence of those anchor aliases, so it’s obvious that they are the same type and can be overridden.